# PhpMyAdmin : Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server

Comment: Have you created the controluser account in MySQL or just add the username and password to `config.inc.php`?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch yes I created controluser account in MySQL

Comment: Can you try connecting directly using the controluser and controlpass you've created? Can you check the host value of that user, also, to verify that it is able to connect from your webserver?